# Как изменить масштаб графика

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Используя ф-ции MovetoEx LineTO как изменить масштаб графика?
При значении x=1 у=60, что за гранью рамки консоли. Вот исходник, помогите пожалуйста.

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(GetConsoleWindow());
HPEN Pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(255, 255, 255));
SelectObject(hDC, Pen);
MoveToEx(hDC, 950, 240, NULL);
LineTo(hDC, 50, 240);
MoveToEx(hDC, 500, 0, NULL);
LineTo(hDC, 500, 500);
MoveToEx(hDC, 100, 230, NULL);
LineTo(hDC, 100, 250);
MoveToEx(hDC, 900, 230, NULL);
LineTo(hDC, 900, 250);
for (float x = xn; x <= xk; x += dx / 100) // O(100,85) - center
{
    MoveToEx(hDC, 200 * x + 500, -10 * (6 * pow(xn, 7) + 1.54*pow(xn, 3) + 6.56) + 180, NULL);
    LineTo(hDC, 500 * x + 500, -10 * (6 * pow(xn, 7) + 1.54*pow(xn, 3) + 6.56) + 180);
}
```

Comment: Не стоит рисовать на консольном окне.

Comment: Я знаю, что можно использовать другие методы построения графика, но у меня задание :)

Comment: Освойтесь с матрицами преобразований. https://code-industry.ru/masterpdfeditor-help/transformation-matrix/
https://habrahabr.ru/post/319144/

Comment: Так а что неполучается то? Какая ошибка?